# Rally Iteration Cumulative Flow Object through WSAPI

Tags: rally

I am trying to obtain Iteration Cumulative Flow object fields through WSAPI via Java. For some reason, I get blank values for IterationObjectID. Do you know how to resolve it?

Comment: Can you share what your query code looks like?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the IterationObjectID attribute is not being returned when querying the Iteration Cumulative Flow object via WSAPI 1.43 or earlier. However, you can retrieve this same attribute when querying the Iteration Cumulative Flow object via WSAPI 2.0. Rally Support is currently investigating this matter.